# Automatic file transfer between two linux machines

Tags: linux, file-transfer

Hi I have two linux machines. Server A (LUbuntu) and Server B (Raspbian). What I want to do is have Server A check in specific a directory(NFS mounted on A) from Server B and IF there are any files transfer them to a location on server A. Ideally after the transfer, any transfered files on B are deleted. Note, that I do not want to sync A and B and I do not want any transfer from A--->B but only from B--->A. Also ideally, i do not want to transfer duplicate files but just delete them.

What is the best way to achieve this without too much srcipting?
Since A is not online all the time, resuming file transfer is important.

Are there any existing software to do this or do I have to script everything myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic flaw in this scheme is that there is no way for host B to know when it is safe to copy the files.  What if A is writing a file to the NFS-shared dir, and host B picks up on that file before it is completely written?  Host B will copy the partial file, and if that (partial) copy is successful, it will delete the **entire** file, including the part that it didn't copy, because Host A hadn't finished writing it yet.

That said, this seems like a fairly simple application for `rsync`.  Read the `man` page, particularly the `--partial` option, perhaps the `--checksum` option, and *especially the caveat in the section about the* `--remove-source-files` option.  The suggested workaround of using filenames such as `*.new` when host A writes files to be copied by host B, then renaming the `.new` files to whatever its name is supposed to be, may work for you.  Renaming within a single filesystem is generally an atomic operation, so host B just has to be patient and ignore any *.new files.  Once they get renamed, host B will transfer them the next time the `cron` job runs.

Comment: yeah perhaps I can script the rsync to only start when say the md5 checksum match the known file signature. Because I (think I) know the md5 sigs before the files are saved to server B or server A. So the rsync can fire and start copying to server A once we know that the file exists complete at server B. So something as follows: Check MD5 on server B. if ok means server B has complete file (and wont write to it again). Then copy to A. Check MD5 on server A. if ok then A has the complete file. Then delete from B.

Comment: @vzografos Wouldn't just using a filename suffix be a lot simpler, such as the rsync man page suggests?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **rsnapshot**.

it is a perl base script, scripting already done for you, just edit its `/usr/local/etc/rsnapshot.conf` file and specify *source* and *destination* for the copy.

Then you run `/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot`  *is where I think the executable gets put*

To run that automatically: `crontab -e` and do something like

```
0 12 * * *   /usr/local/bin/rsnapshot daily
```

crontab syntax is :

```
minute   hour   day_of_month   month   day_of_week
```

per my crontab syntax, would run whatever specified at 12:00pm everyday

```
0 22 * * 2  /usr/local/bin/rnsapshot daily   # will run at 8:00pm only every Monday
```

*read the rsnapshot instructions regarding the daily input argument to the rsnapshot perl script*

rsnapshot can copy between anything, provided you set everything up everything needed [described in instructions]

Comment: hi thanks for the info.  I have tried it but I think I will need to read the help files more carefuly.  I seem to be copying the full path inside the alpha.X snapshots and not just the files. Also I want to avoid making various snapshot directories in the destination folder but only copying the files. I d rather have a program that moves the files instead of taking snapshots of a directory all the time